# Geoserver uses geometry, not geography

Tags: geoserver, geometry, geography

When using a SQL database as the store, Geoserver requires that the spatial data are stored in a `geometry`, not `geography` column. Naturally, as we are dealing with geospatial features and not just Euclidean planar geometry, one would expect the opposite to be true.

Is there any reason for this? Am I missing something important about these two datatypes?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I tried this with MS SQL 2008. But I believe that JDBC used by GeoServer is a quite universal interface, so I don't think this is related to a particular DB... or is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear as to what backend database you are using? Also need to know the version of GeoServer as well to give a definitive answer. For PostGIS geography is supported in recent versions of geoserver 2.1. If you are referring to SQL server then I do not believe geography support is implemented.

Comment: I am using Geoserver 2.1.2 and yes, the DB is MSSQL. If PostGis works fine, then it is probably a bug in the MSSQL plugin for Geoserver.

Comment: As of today, 7 years later, Geoserver still doesn't support Geography data type from Microsoft SQL Server?? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330897/sql-server-spatial-data-geometry-type

Answer (score 2):

You may want to ask this on the geoserver mailing list - http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Mailing+Lists

At least with PostGIS, a geography type is distinct from a geometry type. There's a little information [here](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/geography.html) but basically (as you probably already know):

- `geography` is for spherical
- `geometry` is for cartesian

In the case of web-mapping in general, the defacto coordinate system has become Mercator/Web-mercator which is cartesian and therefore should be stored in `geometry`.